# How to create a realtime 3D walkthrough with Blender?

Tags: rendering, game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I am not a game developer and its not my domain. I am a Biotechnology student. A part of my project requires making a realtime walkthrough of a 3D house. Someone suggested me to use Blender. But here I have more specification : - a walkthrough in 3D such that movement of the user is not through the keypads or mouse but some external running script, where if a particular condition is true, user should move forward, backward, left or right (according to conditions).

What all tutorials I should go through and whatever I am trying to achieve how should I go about approaching it ?

Comment: This is a very broad and vague subject, there are lots of ways to go about doing it. The way I see it you may either use the Blender Game Engine https://www.blender.org/manual/game_engine/index.html with some python scripting, or a third party more modern solution like Blend4Web http://www.blend4web.com/en/ that can run on any modern web browser through WebGL and can be customized through JavaScript

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "external running script". How do you want to communicate with your game (e.g. tcp, udp, http, file sharing, database access ...)

Comment: Very vague question as the others said. Can you update to be more specific?